# IFrame not working properly in MVC with regards to _Layout scripts & styles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

**Setup:**

1. My _layout page has the @Render tag in a span with a display to none.
2. Above the @Render tag there is an Iframe.
3. My menu navigation (as a Partial in _Layout) has a jquery.click event that populates the Iframe with the respective views.

**Problem:**

1. Although when doing "view source" on any page I 'click' into the IFrame from the menu navigation,  I can see my script and style files encoded in the _Layout, they are having no effect on any of the views embedded on the IFrame.
2. How can I get my script & styles files to work again while still maintaining an IFrame structure?